# Xamarin UI Test - test life cycle app(return to app)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, lifecycle, ui-testing

I created Android app with Xamarin Forms. I use Xamarin UI Test for testing life cycle app. I need events for app  - OnStart, OnSleep,  OnResume. 
 My algorithm:
 1. Start test, check UI (OnStart).
 2. App goes to the background(OnSleep). For this I use this code:

in Activity

```
    [Export("GoOut")]
    public void GoOut()
    {
        var uri = Uri.Parse("http://www.google.ru");
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

in Test

```
  app.Invoke("GoOut");
```

It work. Now I need to go back to the app. I want to trigger an event OnResume and testing my app. How to do it?

I tried this:

```
 app.Invoke("GoOut");
 app.Back();
```

and this

```
     //in Activity  
     [Export("Back")]
     public void Back()
     {
        this.OnBackPressed();
     }

    //in my test
    app.Invoke("GoOut");
    app.Invoke("Back");
```

But it not work for me.how Can I go back to the application from browser?

Answer (score 1):

It was easy:

```
ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp(AppDataMode.DoNotClear);
```